# How can I ping via an alternate gateway?

Tags: linux, routing, ping, gateway

Our network has two modems, each one hidden behind a router. The primary router is on 10.1.1.1, the backup router is on 10.1.1.2, and are both configured to the 10.1.1.0/24 subnet. Both routers have their gateway configured to 192.168.0.1. However, the 192.168.0.1 that you see if your gateway is 10.1.1.1 is a different machine from the 192.168.0.1 that you see if your gateway is 10.1.1.2.

My Nagios server is set up accordingly:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 10.1.1.10
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 10.1.1.1
```

So to be clear: there are four gateways here. Router1 (10.1.1.1) Router2 (10.1.1.2) Modem1 (192.168.0.1) Modem2 (192.168.0.1)

Here's an illustration of what I can do manually to check the status of the two modems:

```
ping -c4 192.168.0.1 # Is Modem1 up? 
ip route add via 10.1.1.2
ip route change default via 10.1.1.2
ping -c4 192.168.0.1 # Is Modem2 up?
wget 192.168.0.1 # yields expected control webpage for Modem2
ip route change default via 10.1.1.1
ip route del default via 10.1.1.2
wget 192.168.0.1 # Connection refused; Modem1 has no web interface
ssh adminuser@192.168.0.1 # I can log in to Modem1 and check status
```

I would like at a minimum to be able to ping Modem2.

*Edited to correct my abominable misuse of CIDR notation, and provide clear detail.

Comment: What is the IP configuration from which you are initiating the ping from?

Answer (score 13):

`man ping`

ping [hop... ] destination

So you can give ping a number of IPs separated by white space as parameter. The last address will be "pinged"; the previous parameters define the route that ping should take.

So in your case:

- "ping 10.1.1.2 modem" to explicitly use the first gateway,
- "ping 10.1.1.1 modem" to explicitly use the second gateway.

If you encounter the same problem with Windows:
`ping /?` `-k` is the option you probably want.

BTW: The above ping does not require any root privileges. The routing information (in your case: the "whishlist") is part of the ICMP protocol.

Comment: That's not getting me there. `ping -c4 10.1.1.2 192.168.0.1` yields 100% packet loss. I've clarified the situation above.

Comment: This actually doesn't work at all, even with root. I tested this with while watching `tcpdump`, and it does not do what you think it does.

Comment: What happens if you remove the default-gateway completely?
I still don`t understand your setup. Why do you use the identical "router" address on both modems?

Comment: Both of the modems are controlled by my different ISPs.

Comment: Ok - I now understand the same IP of the routers. Is this an on-demand-connection and you want to failover?

Comment: I just want to be alerted. If they both go down we're cut off from the outside world except by radio and an unreliable backup sat-phone. (Failover would be dangerous since we could easily blow through the 200MB fair access policy before anyone noticed.)

Answer (score 12):

Neither `ping -N` nor `arping` worked for me, I finally settled with the solution from [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/311849/how-can-i-ping-via-an-alternate-gateway/311851#311851):

You can use the tool **nping** from the **nmap** package:

`# nping --icmp --dest-mac [gateway mac] [target ip]`

You can find your router's mac in your local ARP cache:

`$ arp -v [gateway ip]`

The tool also supports different ping types, like `--tcp` or `--udp`.

Comment: Thanks for this. Your suggestion of using nping is the only method I have found (other than adding in a specific route and using the normal ping binary) of sending ICMP echo-requests (pings) towards a dial-on-demand 3G backup router (for testing purposes, to make sure it connects and has real internet connectivity once connected), achieved by targeting the MAC address of the router when sending the ICMP packets, which nping allows you to do. Very useful little utility!

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, you can only have one **default** gateway. You can have multiple gateways, but only one for every network.

The problem is, that both mentioned IPs are in the same network. Also you specified your CIDRs wrongly: You meant 10.1.1.0/24 as having a subnet of 255.255.255.0; or even have a bigger subnet e.g. 10.0.0.0/8 as being 255.0.0.0.

You can therefore ping any host inside your network (10.0.0.0/8) or any host reachable via a (or the) gateway. But having two gateways for the same network is not possible.

Comment: I meant 10.1.1.1/24 as a shorthand for 10.1.1.1 on the 10.1.1.0/24 subnet. Sorry, I won't use that shorthand again, it's clearly wrong. I still have a monitoring problem - I've added more detail above. I cannot solve this problem without putting a better router in place at 10.1.1.2?

Answer (score 2):

Use [arping](http://freshmeat.net/projects/arping/):

```
# arping -c 1 -S [source_ip] -T [target_remote_ip] [gateway_mac_address]
```

Where:

- source_ip is an IP that's locally assigned on your host
- target_remote_ip is the IP address you want to ping
- gateway_mac_address is the layer 2 ether address of the *alternate* gateway you want to use

Alternatively if you're using some form of Solaris you can use:

```
ping -N [gateway_ip] [target_remote_ip]
```

Comment: That looks promising, though I guess iproute2's arping isn't going to cut it... maybe I just need to replace the router with something I can ssh into.

Comment: `iproute2`'s `arping` is different. If you're using arping from `iproute2` to do gratuitous arps, I would suggest using `send_arp` from `fake` instead. Also, the gateway must be something that will forward IP packets.