# Failover between multiple gateways

Tags: linux, networking, centos, failover

I have a CentOS server running [Centreon](https://www.centreon.com) (a monitoring solution similar to Nagios) to monitor devices in multiple networks. The server could access the internet via 4 different gateways/routers, each having its own physical internet connection (ADSL and/or LTE).

Right now I have set one of them as gateway and if this line fails, the server can no longer reach the internet. **How can I automatically switch to another gateway if one fails?**

This also raises the question: how can I detect that an internet connection has failed?

- pinging the router would only detect failures between the server and the router
- Checking via SNMP if DSL is considered `up` leads to many false positives. Because somehow the DSL is up/synced but the problem seems to be on the provider side.
- pinging a host in the internet might lead to false negatives if this host fails. Also: which host should I ping?

  - Google DNS (8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4) might fail sometimes
  - DNS server of provider changes from time to time
  - first hop after router: also changes sometimes
- pinging one of the other gateways also leads to false negatives

The next question would be: How can I check which of the other three connections are still working?

Answer (score 2):

Actually, your question contains two parts.

First, how to make sure the HA between your server and router.
Second, how to make sure the HA between your router and internet.

For the first question, you need two physical enterprise routers. There are dedicated protocols for this purpose, such as HSRP,VRRP,GLBP.

For the second question, I would suggest you to track the www.google.com. Normally this site should be always available.

Comment: For cost reasons enterprise routers are not an option. I found this Answer which shows how to ping via a different gateway http://superuser.com/questions/311849/how-can-i-ping-via-an-alternate-gateway/807289#807289

Comment: Then you may need to purchase a dual/multiple WAN router. It is much cheaper than an enterprise router. The script will not be so stable than a hardware which is dedicated for HA.

Comment: I agree it is not as stable. But I have not seen any multiple WAN router which checks if the connection really works. They can all detect that the cable has disconnected or that the DSL is not connected. But it already happened a few times that the DSL was shown as up, but the ISP had some problems and the connection speed dropped to sth like 100 b/s (yes, bits/second) - which is basically the same as a failure. We have drytek multi-WAN routers, but this kind of error is not detected by them. - and as stated, real HA hardware is to expensive.

Comment: DrayTek just released a new firmware for some of its routers (luckily also the one I have) which adds HA. :-)

Comment: @masgo Glad to hear that!